# Sort alphabetically listview populated from cursor

Tags: android, arrays, sorting, colors

I have a list view populated from a sqlite data fetched with a cursor which was displayed with an adapter, I want to sort the list view on action bar menu click but cursor seems not as straight forward like an array list.

Snippet the receives cursor object and passed to adapter in the onCreate()

```
 databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
    databaseManager.open();

    cursor = databaseManager.queryAllInsects();
    swapCursor(cursor);
    mAdapter = new InsectRecyclerAdapter(this, cursor);
    bugsInsectRecyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

In the optionsItemSelected() where the menu bar would be called to trigger a refresh and sort.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_sort_by_name:
           // WHERE SORTING WOULD BE TRIGGERED tried querying the database again an passing sort order to a cursor seems not working
            Cursor cursor2 = databaseManager.queryAllInsects(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_FRIENDLYNAME);
            swapCursor(cursor2);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

How can I possibly sort the listview populated from cursor alphabetically?

Comment: Why don't you write query which return sorted result?

Comment: ok how would i make the query refresh the cursor that presently populates data to the list view for example this method fethSortedData() returns a sorted result cursor how would I get to change it with the present cursor on menu click

Answer (score 0):

An example with a list of users.

Create a comparator :

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<User> {

    @Override
    public int compare(User x, User y) {
        if (x == null) {
            if (y != null) return -1;
        }
        if (y == null) return 1;

        int startComparison = x.getFirstName().compareTo(y.getFirstName());
        if (startComparison == 0)
            startComparison = x.getLastName().compareTo(y.getLastName());
        return startComparison;
    }
}
```

Then use it :

```
    Collections.sort(userList, new NameComparator() {});
```

Comment: am using a cursor not Arraylist, it could have been straight forward with an ArrayList

Comment: Don't you use List or ArrayList in your RecyclerView ?

Comment: No, I passed the cursor to the adapter and get cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_SCIENTIFICNAME)); like this for values

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting the ArrayList inside the adapter then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. If the data is not changing you could always sort the data given to the adapter before you assign it to the adapter

```
cursor.sort();
mAdapter = new InsectRecyclerAdapter(this, cursor);
```

Comment: this sort() comes from where

Comment: See Sigma's response. If you create a custom Object you have to decide how it gets sorted